# what pattern should I use to print the date,time and process id for the following code?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, process, python-re

I have tried the pattern as: `pattern = r"([a-zA-Z]+ (\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)) \[(\d+)\]:"`
but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import re

def show_time_of_pid(line):
    pattern =___
    result = re.search(pattern, line)
    return ___
    print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)"))
#the output should be in this form: Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with below regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+).*\[(\d+)\]\:
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> p =  "([a-zA-Z]+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+).*\[(\d+)\]\:"
>>> string =  "Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)"
>>> matches = re.search(p, string)
>>> matches.group(1)
'Jul 6 14:01:23'
>>> matches.group(2)
'29440'
>>>
```

Comment: But why ' .* ' doesn't includes the characters between them?

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt include characters between them? `.*` with match 0 or more occurrence of everything except new line character

Comment: `<re.Match object; span=(0, 41), match='Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]:'>` Good, it matches all the characters...thanks a lot.